# UnsatisfiedDependencyException during server start up

Tags: grails-3.3

I am upgrading a grails application from 2.x to 3.3.9. I have run into UnSatisfiedDependencyException with stacktrace that I dont understand. Stack trace is below. What is interesting is at the end of the stacktrace message it says - could not determine type for ....PlatformTransactionManager at table - "table name", for column - "transaction_manager". There is NEITHER a column by that name in the table NOR is it defined in the domain object.

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling 
refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:  

Could not determine type for: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager, at table: TABLE_A, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(transaction_manager)]
```

Comment: JavaProgrammer - did you work out what the problem was here? I am getting exactly the same problem with upgrading from 2.* to 3.3.11?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654552/db-connectivity-fails-in-grails-5-application-with-error-creating-hibernatedatas.