# DB connectivity fails in grails 5 application with error creating hibernateDatastore

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I am upgrading an application to grails-5. I have moved my DB connectivity information from a custom DataSource.groovy to application.yml.
environments:
development:
dataSource:
dbCreate: update
url: jdbc:mysql://hostName:port/DbName?user=x;password=y

The credentials are correct however the application fails to start up and throws the following error.

```
springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to i
nstantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager, at t
able: <<table_name>>, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(transaction_manager)]
```

Comment: It looks like you may have a property named `transactionManager` in some entity that is being mapped to the database.  There are a number of reasons that might happen.  One is a domain class marked with `@Transactional`.  It is difficult to say for sure without seeing code though.

Comment: This may be a similar issue to the one you asked a few years ago at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416278/unsatisfieddependencyexception-during-server-start-up

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, you are right. It is indeed happening on a class that has `@Transactional annotation`. Can you help me understand why @Transactional causes this? I am confused because in grails 2 it just worked fine.

Comment: "Can you help me understand why @Transactional causes this?" - The annotation has an AST transformation associated with it which adds transactional management related code to the class, including the `transactionManager`.  There are no good reasons to ever mark a domain class with `@Transactional`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `@Transactional` on a domain class (which there is no good reason to do) that will result in a property named `transactionManager` being added to the class.  That is required in order for the transaction management logic to be carried out.  The problem is that properties in a domain class are by default mapped to the database unless they are configured as transient.

You should remove the `@Transactional` annotation from the domain class and move any transactional logic wherever transactions are being managed, which frequently is in a transactional Service.

Comment: Thank you! Yes. `@Transactional` on domain class was the source of the problem. I got past this problem by simply removing this annotation. I did not have this problem in grails-2 for some reason. But this problem is now resolved! Thanks again!

Comment: "I did not have this problem in grails-2 for some reason." - Our implementation has changed since Grails 2.